# Can we configure Application Insight for Sitecore XConnect Logs

Tags: xconnect, application-insights

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2 and i have configured Application Insight in CM,CD,Processing And Reporting. Can we configure application insight for XConnect Logs, Xconenct is using Serilog and i did not find any article which is explaining how to configure application insight for XConenct. Could any one help me on this?